# Shutdown or reboot system from LAN

Tags: python, linux, cherrypy

I've written a simple web service which allows a user to shutdown or reboot a system from the LAN. Although written to be used on an RPI which lacks a power or reset button, it can be used on any Linux system.

Aside from the missing secure login (I'm assuming everyone on the network can be trusted at this moment), I'd like to know if there are potential vulnerabilities in this script. Other comments are welcome too.

```
# This script serves a simple web page on port 8080 which allows the server to be shut down or restarted remotely.
# Both the shutdown and reboot executables must be executable by the owner of the process.
# If sudo access is required, ensure no password is required by using NOPASSWD.
# EXAMPLE: username myuser = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot

import cherrypy
from os import system

cherrypy.server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0'

class PyController(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <form method="post" action="shutdown">
            <button type="submit">Shut down</button>
            </form>
            <form method="post" action="restart">
            <button type="submit">Restart</button>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>"""

    @cherrypy.expose
    def shutdown(self):
        system('sudo shutdown -h now')

    @cherrypy.expose
    def restart(self):
        system('sudo reboot')


cherrypy.quickstart(PyController())
```